# using Dapper the way EF Core does it wrongly returns what SQL does

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, relational-database, dapper

Entities:

```
public record ProductAttribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Link { get; set; }
    public AttributeType Type { get; set; }
    public List<ProductAttributeValues> AttributeValues { get; set; } = new();
}

public record ProductAttributeValues
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public string? value { get; set; }
    public int ProductAttributeId { get; set; }

    public ProductAttribute ProductAttribute { get; set; } = new();
}
```

I am trying to use Dapper to get `ProductAttribute`s with its `ProductAttributeValues` in it the way EF Core does it with `.Include()`.

SQL:

```
select pa.Id,pa.Name,pa.link,pa.Type,pav.Id as AttributeId,pav.Name,pav.value,pav.ProductAttributeId
from productattributes pa
inner join productattributevalues pav
on pav.ProductattributeId = pa.Id
```

C#:

```
var attributeResult = await connection.QueryAsync
<ProductAttribute, ProductAttributeValues, ProductAttribute>(sql, (attributes, attributevalues) => {
attributes.AttributeValues.Add(attributevalues);
return attributes;
}, splitOn: "AttributeId");
```

For each `attributevalue` in `ProductAttribute`, one row is returned:

[image]

It should return two `Attribute`s and in one of them 3 `attrValue`s. It returns the same as the SQL:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Chris Shaller, the EF became a very powerful tool in terms of performance.

But to follow on your approach, you have to group your results:

```
    var result = attributeResult.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(g =>
    {
        var productAttribute = g.First();
        productAttribute.AttributeValues = g.Select(p => p.AttributeValues).ToList();
        return productAttribute;
    });
```

Here is the documentation: https://www.learndapper.com/relationships